# Conceptual issue with range based iteration over multiple std containers using boost

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost

I have a function which "zips" multiple containers for range based foor loop iteration. (taken from a another Stack Overflow post)

```
template<class... Conts>
auto zip_range(Conts&... conts)
  -> decltype(boost::make_iterator_range(boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(conts.begin()...)),
              boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(conts.end()...)))) {
  return {boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(conts.begin()...)),
      boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(conts.end()...))};
}
```

I can use this function like so:

```
std::vector<int> x({1,2,3});
std::vector<int> y({4,5,6});
for ( auto const& entries : zip_range(x,y) ) {
  std::cout << entries.get<0>() << " " << entries.get<1>() << std::endl;
}
```

And get expected behavior:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

If I try to define a function which takes two `std::initizalizer_list` arguments, passes them to a vector, and tries to loop:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
void foo(const std::initializer_list<T1>& il1,
         const std::initializer_list<T2>& il2) {

  std::vector<T1> v1(il1);
  std::vector<T2> v2(il2);

  for ( auto const& zipitr : zip_range(v1,v2) ) {
    std::cout << zipitr.get<0>() << " " << zipitr.get<1>() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I get a compilation error that isn't very helpful:

```
testing.cpp: In function ‘void foo(const std::initializer_list<_Tp>&, const std::initializer_list<T2>&)’:
testing.cpp:34:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
     std::cout << zipitr.get<0>() << " " << zipitr.get<1>() << std::endl;
                            ^
testing.cpp:34:58: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
     std::cout << zipitr.get<0>() << " " << zipitr.get<1>() << std::endl;
```

Why am I unable to do this? (much less go straight to giving the initializer lists to the function `zip_range`)

Comment: Perhaps `zipitr.template get<0>()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `zipitr` is dependent on `T1` and `T2` and that type has a nested member function template `get`. So to tell the compiler `get` is a dependent function template, you need to add the `template` keyword immediately before it.

```
std::cout << zipitr.template get<0>() << " " << zipitr.template get<1>() << std::endl;
//                  ^^^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^^^
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/241631) for details of why this is needed.

An alternative that avoids the `template` keyword is to use the `boost::get` free function.

```
std::cout << boost::get<0>(zipitr) << " " << boost::get<1>(zipitr) << std::endl;
```

---

Your `zip_range` function can be simplified (or replaced) using [`boost::combine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/combine.html)

```
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>

template<class... Conts>
auto zip_range(Conts&... conts)
-> decltype( boost::combine(conts...) )
{
  return boost::combine(conts...);
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a7f0997c0a53235)

---

The reason you can't pass `{1,2,3}` directly to `zip_range` is that a *braced-init-list* is not an expression, so it doesn't have a type, which means template argument deduction cannot work.

`auto` has a special rule to deal with them that allows it to deduce the type as `std::initializer_list<T>`, so the following works:

```
auto l1 = {1,2,3};
auto l2 = {4,5,6};
for ( auto const& zipitr : zip_range(l1,l2) ) {
  std::cout << boost::get<0>(zipitr) << " " << boost::get<1>(zipitr) << std::endl;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8f48ad2ef585ba0)